# Как добавить все созданные числа в массив?

Tags: java, массивы, переменные

Нужно все числа, которые были созданы, добавить в массив. Мне нужно, чтобы числа шли по возрастанию, с `random`-возрастанием от +1 до +5.

```java
public class ask3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n0;
        int n1 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 5 );
        int n2 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 5 );
        System.out.print(n1+" ");
        for(int i = 3; i < 100; i++){           
            n0 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 5 );
            n2=n1+n0;
            System.out.print(n2+" ");
            n0 =(int) (1 + Math.random() * 5 );
            n1 =n0+n2;
            System.out.print(n1+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Пробовал так:

```java
public class ytr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n0;
        int n1 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 5 );
        int n2 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 5 );
        System.out.print(n1+" ");
        int n = 100;
        int[] randoms = new int[n];
        for(int i = 3; i < 100; i++){           
            n0 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 5 );
            n2=n1+n0;
            System.out.print(n2+" ");
             randoms[i] =n2+0;
            n0 =(int) (1 + Math.random() * 5 );
            n1 =n0+n2;
            System.out.print(n1+" ");
             randoms[i] = n1 + 0;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randoms));
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод:

```java
[0, 0, 0, 10, 15, 17, 22, 27, 31, 39, 45, 49, 55, 59, 65, 71, 77, 87, 89, 94, 102, 108, 114, 123, 128, 134, 142, 145, 152, 156, 160, 167, 176, 181, 184, 189, 194, 199, 205, 215, 219, 226, 235, 239, 248, 256, 264, 270, 275, 282, 287, 295, 299, 306, 309, 315, 323, 328, 332, 338, 346, 353, 356, 361, 364, 370, 375, 381, 390, 397, 400, 404, 411, 415, 423, 431, 437, 443, 451, 457, 466, 475, 483, 493, 496, 500, 507, 510, 513, 517, 523, 530, 535, 540, 548, 553, 562, 569, 573, 579]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так :

```
int n = 100;
int[] randoms = new Random().ints(n,1,5).toArray();
for (int i = 1; i < randoms.length; i++) randoms[i]+=randoms[i-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Все просто,

```
1 + (int)(Math.random() * 4)
```

Вам нужен интервал рандома 4, а не 5